# I cant setup Google cloud run on europe-west2, does anyone know why this might be

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am new to Google cloud and have just signed up to their free program. I want to use Google Cloud Run to manage my CI/CD stuff but when I push I get the following error

" Your build failed to run: generic::failed_precondition: due to quota restrictions, cannot run builds in this region"

I cant see anywhere where there in no quota setup and am now stuck. I'm trying this on europe-west2. Should this work or is there something else I need to do. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I have examined all my quotas and have trued to push multiple times but I always get the same error. It does register the to push from bitbucket but fails to build. I am doing this with Docker containers, 1 for angular front end 1 for django back end . Both have same error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why don't you try in another region? At least for testing your app

Answer (score 1):

In GCP you can configure quotas for each service and region. You should check the quotas you have for Cloud Runs and, since your error message says *cannot run **builds***, check them also for Cloud Build.

In GCP, if you access APIs & Services you can see the list of all the services you have and if you click on one of them, you can see the quotas and limits:

[image]

[image]

As you see, you can have limitations per region. **Probably you have reached the limit for the europe-west quota**. You can update the limits if needed.